# How is it possible to collide particles with specific momentum in microscopic scale?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, experimental-physics, collision, scattering, scattering-cross-section

Quantum theory says particles with almost specific momentum are spatially spreaded. (have relatively large spatial scales). Then how is possible to collide them very effectively in microscopic scale? (specially in scattering experiments).

I have a sense that when they spread in space their effect also spreads and they couldn't collide very effectively to be destroyed, produce new particles and so on. (Weinberg says: "... several particles approach each other from a macroscopically large
distance, and interact in a microscopically small region,...")

May be one answer be spatial scale of a particle with specific momentum just is not zero but is of microscopic scale (and they are wave-packets and very small in space). I think this couldn't be good answer because in 2slit-experiment we see that this specific-momentum particles are such spatially spreaded that could interact with both of slits.

Comment: The reason the theory of quantum mechanics dominates the mathematical models  for small distances is because of such questions as you have, where you are trying to use classical scattering intuition at the microscopic level. One has to develop quantum mechanical intuition, which is mainly based that a particle does not have a trajectory  but a **probability** of being on the (x,y,z,t) of a classical trajectory. This means an accumulation of measurements can be predicted, not  classical collision of trajectories , when two particle trajectories interact.

Comment: Is this picture is true in context of QM and QFT: Shooting two particles with specific momentum at each other is like shooting two clouds of probabilities to each other. in many cases no effective collision occurs but in a very small fraction of such shootings, an effective collision occurs and in this case  annihilation creation of particles may happen. @annav

Comment: (Continuation of the previous comment) I mean clouds with macroscopic sizes. If this pictures is wrong could it be corrected with small edits? @annav

Comment: The Quantum field theory calculations assume the particles are **point** particles,  and the probabilistic cloud you envision comes from the calculations that can only be checked with an **accumulation** of same boundary conditions etc scatterings. Not particle on particle. It is the probability of creation and annihilation that can be checked, and it is a continuous function of the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a straightforward process to prepare a particle beam so that most of the particles in it have nearly the same kinetic energy or momentum, and then collide that beam with another headed in the opposite direction.

Those collisions happen even though when we prepare a particle with a well-defined momentum, its exact position becomes ill-defined.

You make up for the fact that their effective *cross-section* for collisions is small and/or you don't know where exactly they are within the beam by bunching a very large number of particles into each beam. Eventually, two of these particles will experience a head-on collision even though their original positions within the beam were uncertain or actually undefined.